# Problem with ViewData in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have following tables in my application:

BookCatalogue

--ID(PK)

--BookName

--AuthorID(FK)

Author

--ID(PK)

--FirstName

--LastName

In Edit view for bookCatalogue I want to display not textbox for ID but list of authors.

This is my code:

Controller

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        ViewData["Authors"] = _authorRepository.GetAllAuthors();
        var book = _bookCtalogueRepository.GetBookById(id);
        if (book == null)
            throw new Exception("Book not found");
        return View(book);
    }
```

View(this displays only LastName)

```
...
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Author)
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.DropDownList("ID", new SelectList(ViewData["Authors"] as System.Collections.IEnumerable,
         "ID", "LastName" , Model.AuthorID))
        </div>
...
```

I have two problems:

1) How to combine FirstName and Lastname in one DropDownList?

2) When I change LastName and BookName and try to save changes only new BookName is changed.

This is my code for saving changes

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
    {
        var book = _bookCtalogueRepository.GetBookById(id);
        if (TryUpdateModel(book))
        {
            _bookCtalogueRepository.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            ViewData["Genres"] = _genreRepository.GetAllGenres();
            ViewData["Authors"] = _authorRepository.GetAllAuthors();
            return View(book);
        }
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Where are you changing your last name at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to combine FirstName and Lastname in one DropDownList?

```
ViewData["Authors"] = _authorRepository
    .GetAllAuthors()
    .Select(a => new { 
        ID = a.ID,  
        FullName = string.Format("{0} {1}", a.FirstName, a.LastName) 
    });
```

and then:

```
@Html.DropDownList(
    "ID", 
    new SelectList(
        ViewData["Authors"] as System.Collections.IEnumerable,
        "ID", 
        "FullName", 
        Model.AuthorID
    )
)
```